# Всем привет, строю прогноз курса биткоина, использую множественную линейную регрессию. Проблема в том, что прогнозные значения получаются одинаковыми/

Tags: python, python-3.x

Данные беру с https://www.blockchain.com/ru/charts#block.

Мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';', index_col=['Time'], dayfirst=True)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%d.%m.%Y')
data = data.resample('W').mean()
y = data['market_price']
x = data.drop(['market_price'], axis=1)

models = [# LinearRegression(),  # метод наименьших квадратов
          RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, max_features='sqrt'),  # случайный лес
          # KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=6),  # метод ближайших соседей
          # SVR(kernel='linear'),  # метод опорных векторов с линейным ядром
          ]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

model = models[0].fit(X_train, Y_train)

r_2 = {'R2_Y': r2_score(Y_test, model.predict(X_test))}
print(r_2)

pred_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'pred': model.predict(X_test),
    'real': Y_test
})

pred_test.plot()
plt.show()

new_dates = pd.date_range('2021-05-09', '2022-01-02', freq='W')
new_dates = pd.Index(x.index) | new_dates
x2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': new_dates})
y2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': new_dates})
x_new = pd.merge(x, x2, on='Time', how='right')
y_new = pd.merge(y, y2, on='Time', how='right')
x_new = x_new.set_index('Time')
x_new = x_new.fillna(0)
y_new = y_new.set_index('Time')

model_2 = models[0].fit(x, y)

r_2 = {'R2_Y': r2_score(y, model_2.predict(x))}
print(r_2)

pred = pd.DataFrame({
    'pred': model_2.predict(x_new),
    'real': y_new.market_price
})

pred.plot()
plt.show()
```

И вот результат:
[image: результат на тренировочной выборке]

[image: результат прогноза]

Пример данных:

```
            market_price  trade_volume      hashrate  transactions_per_day
Time                                                                      
2016-05-08    452.953333  9.812436e+05  1.409150e+06         227158.000000
2016-05-15    453.300000  1.940460e+06  1.337420e+06         235977.500000
2016-05-22    445.025000  2.009665e+06  1.400187e+06         201746.500000
2016-05-29    471.270000  3.097414e+06  1.520550e+06         218714.666667
2016-06-05    549.925000  5.691195e+06  1.302883e+06         227920.000000
```

Кто знает в чем может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Где конкретно они у вас одинаковые? По графику видно что предсказанные значения разные, и примерно повторяют график реальных значений.

Comment: Я имею ввиду что сам прогноз падает в низ и держится на значении примерно 1200( 2й график)

Answer (score 1):

Что-то странное у вас в программе:

```
x2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': new_dates})
```

Вы создаете датафрейм, в котором данных как таковых нет.

```
x_new = pd.merge(x, x2, on='Time', how='right')
x_new = x_new.fillna(0)
```

В этом датафрейме часть данных (та которая от х) -  это нормальные данные, а вторая часть (та которая от x2) -  нули.

```
model_2.predict(x_new)
```

И теперь по этим нулевым данным вы делаете предсказания???

В скобках замечу, что RandomForestRegressor -  это вовсе не множественная линейная регрессия, заявленная в названии вопроса.

Comment: я понимаю, тогда может подскажите (или же источник) как построить прогноз на год вперед например? То есть по test train все строится и работает вроде хорошо, а как именно построить прогноз по тем значениям которых нет в датасете.

Comment: Подскажу. Открываете любой учебник по Теории временнЫх рядов. В нем как правило есть тема "Прогнозирование с помощью временных рядов" или как-то аналогично. Изучаете. Применяете.  Но это только первый шаг. Потому как у вас многомерный временнОй ряд, в котором значения (как вам кажется) зависят не только от времени, но и от других параметров (иначе зачем вы использовали множественную регрессию). Поэтому переходим к продвинутым разделам указанной теории -  она есть уже не во всех учебниках. Изучаем, применяем. Изложить все это на форуме - даже кратко -  вряд-ли представляется возможным.